# In $K(\alpha)/K$, example of different $K$-automorphisms with the same image of $\alpha$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $F/K$ be a field extension, and let $\alpha \in F$. If $K(\alpha)/K$ is finite, then a $K$-isomorphism $\sigma \colon K(\alpha) \to K(\alpha)$ is uniquely determined by the image of $\alpha$ (as from that we can deduce the image of an arbitrary element by writing the latter as a polynomial expression in $\alpha$ of finite degree and using the homomorphism properties of $\sigma$).

Is there an example, when $K(\alpha)/K$ is infinite, of $K$-isomorphisms $\sigma, \sigma' \colon K(\alpha) \to K(\alpha)$ with $\sigma(\alpha) = \sigma'(\alpha)$ but $\sigma \ne \sigma'$?

Comment: No. To properly explain why, how do you define $K(\alpha)$? Also, there's a (presumably) typo at the start, because if $\alpha\in K$, then $K(\alpha)=K$ and nothing interesting happens.

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks for catching the typo. $K(\alpha)$ is defined as the smallest field extension $E$ of $K$ (with $K \subseteq E \subseteq F$) containing both all of $K$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: Hint: $K(\alpha)$ is also the set of values $p(\alpha) / q(\alpha)$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials with coefficients in $K$ and $q(\alpha) \neq 0$. (If you don't already have this theorem, it's not hard to show from that definition of $K(\alpha)$.)

Comment: Alright, so here's a suggestion: Consider $\{x\in K(\alpha)\mid \sigma(x)=\sigma^{\prime}(x)\}$. Evidently, this contains $K$ and $\alpha$. Prove it is a field and then deduce it equals $K(\alpha)$, whence $\sigma=\sigma^{\prime}$.

Comment: Thanks @Thorgott, I've added an answer below developing this thought, I hope it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the original question is no, there are no such examples.

Following [Thorgott's hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387726/in-k-alpha-k-example-of-different-k-automorphisms-with-the-same-image-of#comment9173488_4387726), we can prove this more general statement:

> Let $F/K$ be a field extension, and let $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in F$. Define $K' := K(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$. Then any $K$-automorphism $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(K'/K)$ is uniquely determined by the images of $\alpha_1, \ldots \alpha_n$. That is, if $\sigma' \in \mathrm{Gal}(K'/K)$ and $\sigma'(\alpha_i) = \sigma(\alpha_i)$ for all $i$, then $\sigma' = \sigma$.

Indeed, define the set:
$$ A := \{x \in K' \mid \sigma(x) = \sigma'(x)\} \subseteq K' $$
Then:

- **$A$ is a subfield of $F$.** Indeed:

  - Since by definition of $\mathrm{Gal}(K'/K)$, both $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ fix $K$ pointwise, we have $1 \in K$ and therefore $1 \in A$. Moreover, since $K$ is a field, $1 \ne 0$, so this means that $A \supsetneq \{0\}$.
  - Let $x, y \in A$. Consider $x - y \in K'$. Then, since $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are ring homomorphisms:
    $$ \sigma(x - y) = \sigma(x) - \sigma(y) = \sigma'(x) - \sigma'(y) = \sigma'(x - y) $$
    So $x - y \in A$.
  - Let $x, y \in A$ with $y \ne 0$. Consider $x/y \in K'$. Then, since $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are ring homomorphisms:
    $$ \sigma(x/y) = \sigma(x)/\sigma(y) = \sigma'(x)/\sigma'(y) = \sigma'(x/y) $$
    So $x/y \in A$.

  By the [three-step subfield test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subfield_Test/Three-Step) we conclude that $A$ is a subfield of $F$ (so, in particular, $A$ is a field).
- **$A$ contains $K$ and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$.** Indeed, $K \subseteq A$ is due to the fact that both $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ fix $K$ pointwise. Also, $\alpha_i \in A$ is true by hypothesis ($\sigma(\alpha_i) = \sigma'(\alpha_i)$) for all $i$.

So, by definition, this implies that $K' = K(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n) \subseteq A$. The inclusion $K' \supseteq A$ is direct from construction. Therefore $A = K'$. This means that $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ agree on their entire domain, so $\sigma = \sigma'$.

Comment: Yup, this is entirely correct and very accurate. That said, I think it's generally frowned upon to write $\mathrm{Gal}(K^{\prime}/K)$ for the $K$-automorphisms of $K^{\prime}$ unless $K^{\prime}/K$ is a Galois extension, but perhaps your conventions differ (this is not a substantial issue in any case).